# What were the tests to determine that a substance is an element or not?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What tests were conducted in the ancient days to determine whether a given substance was an element, say, how could one say that mercury, gold, silver, sulphur, phosphorous were elements?

Comment: I think you are projecting a modern concept (element) onto a not-yet-scientific period.

Comment: Not necessarily, but he should not use misleading term ancient for 17th-18th century.

Comment: 1669 is the year of the discovery of Phosphorous attributed to Brand as the last discovery of the elements mentioned by you.  Which is prior to modern chemistry, yet not ancient.

Comment: by ancient is meant when modern tools were not available, say 1669 as mentioned by Buttonwood concerning Phosphorous. Regret use of 'ancient'